# Bilingual Ubiquitious Language

Tags: domain-driven-design

One problem in a project with Domain Driven Design:

In discussions about the domain model, many terms of the Ubiquitous Language (UL) are used in German by the team members (all German speakers) , whereas the English version is used within the analysis model and the code model.

What is good practise to handle this issue? Should we force us to use the English term in discussions also, or is it ok to translate the term for modeling and implementation?

Answer (score 1):

I've also worked in multiple, german DDD projects.
In my experience, the team usually automatically starts to use the english terms as soon as there have been first discussions and a first implementation. It helps if you maintain an up-to-date glossary of the german terms and their english counterparts especially to help new team members.

Answer (score 1):

I think UL is just another language, like german or english are. The point is that it has to be spoken and understood by all team members. And it has to be used every where, discussions, documents, diagrams, source code, ...

You cannot use a german term in discussions and its english translated term in source code.

Answer (score 0):

Working in Germany, I was involved in a banking project once where the Team (all Germans) decided to use English to write code, on the off chance that some offshore team might also later be involved.

A couple of months later we already struggled with our English dictionary. We noticed that we (and the business people) would have no problems with the German words, but we ourselves did not always knew the correct translations in the code. Some concepts (like legal terms, etc.) don't even always have a correct translation.

It got even worse. As some offshore colleagues were involved, they started asking for the German words behind some things in the code, because they could google the German words, but not always the English ones. (Might be caused by our bad translations to English...)

Having gone through all of that, *I would take whatever the "source" language is into the code*. If the source material (requirements, legal framework, business team, etc.) is in German, then German.

The only argument against using German is that it looks and sounds really funny and strange. Oh, and Unicode support is a must. Class "Überweisungsvorlage" vs. CashTransferTemplate.

I know of another Team which combined English verbs in methods with German concepts, like "createÜberweisungsvorlage", because German verbs are quirky and do not lend themselves to short and uniform conventions.

Summary: You decide, and good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Use whichever language your domain experts use. If many, ask them to choose the one that defines the domain best.

The best language can be different from one subdomain/Bounded Context to another.